# How can I set Cache-Control globally in NGINX

Tags: nginx, caching, pragma

I want to setup a general cache-control for all NGINX-Sites.
Here is an example of it:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|svg?z)$ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

If I try to add this "location" setting to */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* I got an error, that I can't set it here.

So is there a way to set this cache handling for all sites in nginx by default, without the need to edit each single host in /sites_available/ ?

Comment: Both `add_header` and `expires` can be set the context of  `http, server, location, if in location` but `location`'s context is `server, location` so you could add the headers and expires but it wouldn't be for a specific location. You could use a shared `include` in the location that does this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use `location` directive in contexts other than `server` or another `location`. However you can use the following workaround (this one can be added to the `http` context):

```
map $cache $public {
    1       public;
}

map $cache $expires {
    1       1y;
    default off; # or some other default value
}

map $uri $cache {
    ~*\.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|svg?z)$    1;
}

expires $expires;
add_header Pragma $public;
add_header Cache-Control $public;
```

nginx won't add the header at all (or modify an existing header) if the value calculated via the `map` expression will be an empty string. But be aware of [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) documentation excerpt:

> There could be several `add_header` directives. These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.